# Algorithm for joining data points in charting frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Is there a way to plot a chart by joining the points as they appear in the input array instead of ordering the array by x-axis asc before joining the points.
For instance:

```
Input Array= [[1, 3], [5, 6], [4, 4], [3, 10]]
```

All the chart frameworks I have examined (jqplot, flot, et al) will sort the Array by x-axis before joining the points. Resulting in:

```
[1, 3] -> [3, 10] -> [4, 4] -> [5, 6]
```

But what I want is to join the points as they appear exactly in the input Array.

```
[1, 3] -> [5, 6] -> [4, 4] -> [3, 10]
```

If you plot these few points as I stated you will observe what I mean. They look different. There is a need that I have to join the points as they appear in the input array and not ordered by x-axis ascending.
Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Highchart.js](http://www.highcharts.com/) and in particular [spline charts](http://docs.highcharts.com/#spline-chart). I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, that's a big step in the right direction. However Highcharts.js is not open source. I am interested in open source software.

Comment: It is however under Creative Commons for non-profit if that might help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any charting framework that considers this data as categorical data on x-axis. [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com), HighCharts etc. allow you to build these charts in JavaScript, with x-axis values treated as categories.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with jqplot. All you need is to set "sortData" option to false
...,
sortData : false,
...,

This ensures that the plot is drawn exactly as the data is fed into the plot engine otherwise the x-axis will be sorted before drawing. Sometimes this is not desirable.